# Not Repeating Words in Swift when clicking button - IOS

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string

How can I not repeat the array when I click on the button in swift? I'm trying to generate fruits without them repeating. Can I sort the string that way it runs through all the fruits one by one? It doesn't have to be randomized. I just want each word to show only once when I click the button and show the last array "There aren't any fruit options left"

I tried to randomize the string but that repeats the fruits. I just want it to go one by one. When I press the button on my screen the output on the image label should give me each fruit one at a time.

ie. Button pressed" 
 Output: "Apple"

button pressed again 
Output: "Banana"

and so on until the last string shows "There aren't any fruit options left"

```
import UIKit

class fruitrandomViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var nextfruitButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var fruitbox: UILabel!

@IBAction func fruitbutton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let array = ["Apple","Banana","Orange","Pinapple", "Plum", "Pear","T"There aren't any fruit options left",]


    let randomFruitgenerator = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
    fruitbox.text = array[randomFruitgenerator]

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to somehow keep track of the array elements that you have already used.  You could do this in a couple of ways:

1. Keep an index property that tracks the next element of the array
2. Mutate the array itself as elements are consumed

Either way, you should make the array an instance property, not a local variable in the function itself.

Here is an example of the second approach (I prefer this since I think it makes the code a little simpler, as you don't need to track the next index).

```
class fruitrandomViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var nextfruitButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var fruitbox: UILabel!

    var fruit = ["Apple","Banana","Orange","Pinapple", "Plum", "Pear",].shuffled()

    @IBAction func fruitbutton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if fruit.isEmpty {
            fruitbox.text = "There's no more fruit left"
        } else {
            fruitbox.text = self.fruit[0]
            self.fruit.remove(at:0)
        }
    }
}
```

For completeness, here is the first approach (with an added "previous fruit" button):

```
class fruitrandomViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var nextfruitButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var fruitbox: UILabel!

    let fruit = ["Apple","Banana","Orange","Pinapple", "Plum", "Pear",].shuffled()
    var nextFruit = 0

    @IBAction func fruitbutton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if nextFruit < fruit.count {
            fruitbox.text = self.fruit[nextFruit]
            nextFruit += 1
        } else {
            fruitbox.text = "There's no more fruit left"

        }
    }

    @IBAction func previousFruitButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        guard nextFruit > 0 else  {  
            return
        }             
        nextFruit -= 1
        fruitbox.text = self.fruit[nextFruit]
    }
}
```

If you don't want the fruit in a random order, just remove the `.shuffled()`

Comment: Thank you! That worked!! Do you know how I can go back to the previous array? For example if I clicked the buttons and Apple, Banana, Orange showed but I wanted to go back to see banana. How would I do that?

Comment: You can't go back in my first example, since the used fruit has been removed from the array; You could have a button that re-initialised the array with by assigning a new shuffle of your fruit.  In the second example you could have a button that decremented `nextFruit` before accessing the array, remembering to check if `nextFruit` is 0 first.

Comment: could you provide an example? Thank you!!

Comment: I added a previous fruit to my second example